# Append filter info to URL when using AJAX in 'View' module

Tags: 7, ajax, views

I am using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module and have created a view for a content type. I have added an exposed filter so that the user can filter the list of content based on a custom taxonomy.

I want to use `AJAX` for filtering the content.  Before I select `'yes'` under `'use AJAX'` in the `'advanced' tab`, the filter appends the filter selection to the URL such as `/content-type-view?category='selected-category'`.  But once I select `AJAX`, I lose the update to the URL.

I want to combine the two, use `AJAX` but also have unique URL's so that I can direct users to pre-filtered instances of the view.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using D7 or D8?

Comment: @CodeNext I am using D7

Comment: And are you using better exposed module also as it is listed in your tags, right?

Comment: Yes, I am using 'better exposed'.  Although the above question is not specific to the 'better exposed' module, I will eventually be using that to 'auto-submit' the filter selected in conjunction with the 'advanced' tab AJAX

Comment: @CodeNext Any help?

Comment: I tried to construct the scenario in my trial site, but I am not able to understand the URL thing. Are you want to say that, the URL is one of teh selection option and if you enable Ajax, you lose the URL link?

Comment: @CodeNext I just want to append the parameters to the URL if I select 'yes' under use AJAX.  The same way the parameters are appended to the URL if AJAX is not used.

Comment: Do I get this right: You want the URL to be updated during an AJAX call?

Comment: @CodeNext yes, just the query parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is manipulate the browser's URL even though there are no page reloads, only AJAX requests taking place.

You are actually in need of the HTML5 History API.

And luckily there seems to be a module available, specific to your case:

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_ajax_history

Give this a try and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this, I have definitely used the HTML5 History API before, but thought that there was a way to make this happen within the Views module.  I'll give the above module a shot and see how it works.  Thanks!

Comment: This worked great, highly recommend.

Comment: Worked for me like a charm, thx!!